# Internal error during upload-pack from /opt/gerrit/git/XXX.git every 5 mins

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

We are getting Internal error during upload-pack from /opt/gerrit/git/XXX.git every 5 mins in the log files.

Below is the error found :

[2016-09-08 00:11:44,675] WARN  / : Internal error during upload-pack from /opt/gerrit/git/xxx.git

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms

I want to know the cause behind it ..any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you know what is the command launch ? Is a command launched automatically by gerrit ?

Comment: No, We do not know about it. We know that it could be pull updates from a remote repository

Comment: Did all your files/folder under `objects` have the same permissions, and gerrit user got the same group than files

Comment: Any answer on my previous comment ?

Comment: Yes, I have just checked it. All files/folders have same permissions

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer here https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#transfer

We need to set the timeout accordingly.Currently it is set to 30000 ms